# google play upload apk failed

Tags: android, google-play, apk

i used appgeyser to make a new android app,
now i'm trying to upload it on google play, 
put there is an error appear 
Your APK needs to have the package name com.wbook2132.

thanks in advance

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: what can i do to solve the problem ?